# How to make my nav menu show over existing text

Tags: html, css

I created a nav menu, but it is displayed under elements instead of over it. When I open the menu, I would like it to appear over whatever is already there and completely block it. I tried using z-index, but I must be doing something wrong, because it doesn't change anything. I read a bunch of stack posts and other web pages on the subject, but I can't figure it out. I have been stuck on it for almost a day, so any advice is more than welcome.

[Picture of the menu under the existing elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr8FF.png)

Here is the html of the menu:

```
<nav id="navMenu">
    <button id="menuButton" class="closedMenu">
        Menu
        <span class="expicon glyphicon glyphiconClosed glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </button>
    <ul>
        (some liquid code)
        {% fetchxml categories_query %}
        <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
           (some liquid code)
        {% endfetchxml %}
        {% for cat in categories %}
        <li>
            <span>(some liquid code)</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>(some liquid code)</a>
                </li>

                {% fetchxml subcat_query %}
                <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true">
                    (some liquid code)
                {% endfetchxml %}

                {% for subcat in subcat_query.results.entities %}
                <li>
                    <a>(some liquid code)</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the css:

```
#menuButton:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
#menuButton {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    border: none;
}
#menuButton:hover, #menuButton:hover .glyphicon {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #335075;
}
.openMenu {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #335075;
}
.closedMenu {
    color: #335075;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#navMenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navMenu > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #335075;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 15em;
}
#navMenu > ul > li:hover ul, #navMenu > ul > li:focus ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 15em;
    width: 25em;
    background-color: red;
}
#navMenu li {
    padding: 0.2em 0 0.2em 0;
}
#navMenu > ul > li{
    border-top: 1px #eee solid;
    padding-left: 1em;
}
#navMenu > ul > li:first-child{
    border:none;
}
#navMenu li:hover {
    color: #335075;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#navMenu li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#navMenu a, #navMenu a:visited, #navMenu a:hover {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
}
#navMenu ul ul li:first-child > a{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1.2em;

}
#navMenu .glyphicon {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    top: -0.2em;
    left: -0.5em;
}
#navMenu .glyphiconClosed {
    color: #335075;
}
#navMenu .glyphiconOpen {
    color: #fff;
}
```

And here is some of the html on the page with the menu with it:

```
<header>
   <nav id:"navMenu>...</nav>
</header>
<main>
   <div class="row">
      <div>
          <h1>Welcome to the Portal-Poc website</h1> 
      <div>
   </div>
   <div>...</div>
   ...
</main>
```

Comment: Use `z-index` to *navMenu*

Comment: I managed to get it working with z-index, but it didn't work when I added z-index to #navMenu. (That's what I also tried before writing this question). It did work when I added z-index directly to the li. Thank you

Comment: Correction. In my previous comments I wrote li element, but I meant the ul. It works by adding z-index to the ul element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `z-index` of the header `#navMenu` must be greater than other elements then it will be on top of other elements while the overlap.

example:

```
.nav {
    z-index: 99;
}

.other-elements {
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding `#navMenu{ z-index:99;} div, h1, h2, h3, a, span, main{ z-index:10;}`, but it didn't work. Then I tried a couple different options and I managed to get it  working, by just adding z-index to the li elements. I assumed the li inside #navMenu would just inherit the z-index value, but it didn't. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to keep all the content part in a div like you used <main> try adding z-index of a lower value to that div and navMenu a higher z-index.

Comment: Correction regarding my previous comment. I said li element, but it is the ul element. So it works when I apply it to the ul element.

Comment: I'll try to do something like that. Thank you